# C# (.net) web service to send data periodically

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to implement a C# web service to get data periodically. I have hosted a web service. Through that I want to get accelerometer data of an android phone periodically. Do I need to write code to the phone application to send data periodically or else can I do that in the web service. In the phone application I have called getData function in the web service.

Answer (score 2):

A WebService is stateless and it doesn't do anything until something calls it.  The best way to handle this is to have the phone be responsible for sending it's own data to the WebService.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to write code in the phone application. The phone is effectively in the driving seat here - it can make periodic requests to the server, but the server can't make requests to the client.

(Things like long polling and web sockets can make the relationship somewhat more equal, but I wouldn't look at anything complicated - it'll be *much* simpler just to make the client post the data periodically.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the webservice to store the information to DB. Then call the webservice from the Android application periodically.